# Reference counting of the object in multithreaded application c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference

I am trying to implement the reference count for the objects in a multithreaded program, so that I can delete the object when none of the threads wants to use it, or someone initiates the object delete.

For that I am doing the following:

```
class refCount{
    int ref_count;

    public:
        void incr_ref_count(){
        ref_count ++;
    } 

    int decr_ref_count(){
        ref_count--;
        return ref_count; 
    }

}
```

And am using the following code whenever I copy the obj in different threads:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&ref_count_lock);
if(obj != NULL){
    dup_obj = obj;
    obj.incr_ref_count(); 
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ref_count_lock);
```

and while removing the reference

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&ref_count_lock);
if(dup_obj != NULL){
    count = dup_obj.decr_ref_count(); 
    if(count == 0)
        delete dup_obj
}   
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ref_count_lock);
```

I was hoping it would work fine, but the problem I think I have is in using the mutexs(Lock), I need to have a mutex(Lock) for each object I create separately, so that I can make copying, and increasing or decreasing the count, to be atomatic. How to implement this?

**Please note its not exactly a working code its kinda sudo code.**

thanks for all the help.

Comment: Both boost and C++11 have a reference counted object that you could use.

Comment: Mutexes are extremely expensive and heavy-weight. For reference counting, you should look at atomics.

Answer (score 3):

Locks kill reference-counting performance.  See for example [Atomic Reference Counting Pointers](http://www.drdobbs.com/atomic-reference-counting-pointers/184401888) for ways to reduce or eliminate the number of locks needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a separate lock object for every object instance you want to protect. If you use one lock object for all object instances, that will guarantee that only one thread at a time can manipulate the reference count. Having multiple lock objects would merely reduce the frequency of thread blocking.

Comment: ya as u said it will work but since each thraed will be accessing multiple of these objects having one lock will block the other threads even though the other threads not accessing the same object.That y wanted to have locks for each objects I create .